# Selection using regex expression

Tags: regex

I have a string where there are several "\\", some of which I want to select for removal using regex, others not. To be more exact, I want to remove all "\\" not inside [...] so for the strings

```
var string1 = "[1 & 2 \\ 1 & 2] \\ [1 & 2 \\ 1 & 2 ]";
var string2 = "a{b}_{c} \\ [1 & 2 \\ 1 & 2 \\ 1 & 2 ]";
var string3 = "[1 & 2 \\ 1 & 2 \\ 1 & 2 ] \\ \text{foo}";
```

Is there a single regex expression that selects the "\\" in "..] \\ [.." in string1, "..} \\ [.." in string2 and "..] \\ \te.." ? Generally there could be any symbol before and after the "\\", the main diffrence is that I want to select only those not inside brackets.

Comment: Are the [ and ] nested?  If so, then you are leaving the possibilities of regex (not a regular grammar any more) and you would need some more advanced type of parser.

Comment: No the [ and ] will not appear as [ [ ] ] or [ [ ] or [ ] ]

Comment: Without your current code, I think it is impossible to help since "selecting" is not clear. Regex only searches for a match. And regex flavors differ from engine to engine.

Comment: I had no idea that regex differs. It's in Javascript and I was planning on using `str.replace(regex, "")`, that  is the only codeline I hade. Of course another solution is to use a for-loop that counts [ and ].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would require using quantifiers (`*`,`+`) in lookbehinds to exclude patterns like `\[[^]]*` (which means it has preceding left square bracket followed by any number of characters except right square bracket), but quantifiers in lookbehinds are impossible.

So maybe you could notice different pattern in your strings - for example, if these pairs of `/` are never followed by a space and digit, while those in brackets always are, you could use this:

```
\\{2}(?!\s\d)
```

[Demo here](https://regex101.com/r/hB1aW4/1)

Comment: This did not answer the original problem but it seems I can modify the strings beforehand to match your regex expression. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

U can use this:

```
(?<=\])( \\{2} )(?=\[)?|((?<=\])?( \\{2} )(?=\[))
```